# How do I combine multiple queries into an array?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables set up.  One for student information, one for student/class listing.  I'm coding in PHP using the sqlsrv plugin for MSSQL 2008 R2.

```
Student ID
Class Code

Student ID
First Name
Last Name
```

I need to select all students from a class but order by last name.

```
SELECT student_id FROM table1 WHERE class_code LIKE '402843'
$students = SELECT last_name, first_name FROM table2 WHERE student_id LIKE 'all results of first query'
```

Right now I can select all the students and display all the information; however, I can not sort them by last name.  I'm sure this is possible, but seeing that the first query will return an array, I need the second query to return an array as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN` subquery:

```
SELECT last_name, first_name FROM table2 WHERE student_id IN (SELECT student_id FROM table1 WHERE class_code='402843') ORDER BY last_name ASC
```

Comment: That worked like a charm.  Thank you very much... the 'in' is new to me, appreciate the help!  Wish I could give you a thousand upvotes.

Comment: No, but It's more complicated and I don't really like joins, as much simplified as possible, I'll give him +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

look at joins in SQL and do it all in your query rather than in PHP...

using your examples and for the purposes of code, naming the tables as follows

```
ClassCodeTable  
    Student ID
    Class Code

StudentInfoTable
    Student ID
    First Name
    Last Name
```

then your query would look like

```
SELECT SI.last_name, SI.first_name FROM StudentInfoTable SI JOIN ClassCodeTable CC on CC.student_id=SI.student_id WHERE CC.class_code LIKE '402843' ORDER BY SI.last_name ASC
```